# Redux Form - You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I want to create a simple form that takes in an email adress and later adds it to our database. I went with React Forms, because it facilitates the whole development process and reduces the amount of time.

However, when I'm trying to POST my form I'm getting this error: Uncaught Error: You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop

Here's my **AddUserForm.js**:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const AddUserForm = ({ handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <Field name="email" component="input" type="email" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Bjud in</button>
    </form>
  )
}
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'addUser'
})(AddUserForm)
```

Here's my **addUserAction**:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import settings from '../settings'

axios.defaults.baseURL = settings.hostname

export const addUser = email => {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.post('/invite', { email: email }).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
  }
}
```

And here's my **AddUserContainer.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { addUser } from '../../actions/addUserAction'
import AddUserForm from './Views/AddUserForm'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class AddUserContainer extends Component {
  submit(values) {
    console.log(values)
    this.props.addUser(values)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Bjud in användare</h1>
        <AddUserForm onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { user: state.user }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addUser })(AddUserContainer)
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I get: `onSubmit` is not defined.

Comment: `export default connect()(reduxForm({
  form: 'addUser',
  onSubmit, })(AddUserForm))`. Also remember to import `connect` from react-redux.

Comment: `onSubmit` is still not defined

Comment: Give me a sec, I will post a full answer.

Comment: Appreciate that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onSubmit` is *not defined* because it's not declared. Follow the path:

**Note**: `values` variable holds fields data, in your case it will hold typed email.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const AddUserForm = ({ handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <Field name="email" component="input" type="email" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Bjud in</button>
    </form>
  )
}

const onSubmit = (values, dispatch) => {
  dispatch(    // your submit action //      );
};

export default connect()(reduxForm({
  form: 'addUser', 
  onSubmit, 
})(AddUserForm));
```

Comment: I understand. So I can pass my action in there? :O

Comment: @MartinNordström Yeah, think so. You can try pasting there whole logic for `axios` request or just function. By the way - where are your actions/reducers etc? :P

Comment: Oh! Didnt see your question. My actions/ reducers are in separate folders, I'm still unceartan how I can apply my reducer to this. And my action for this form is basically just an axios post request.

Comment: If that is the case, why is this working without having to declare the onSubmit function? https://codesandbox.io/s/mZRjw05yp